# PostgreSQL displaying data fetched from query

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql

I am building a data analysis tool in php. I am querying our production server which is Postgres and displaying data.

I'm running my select query (date is passed as a variable) in a loop which display output like this:

1st Iteration :

```
Country     sum(yesterday)  
India       4500  
Southafrica 5000
```

2nd Iteration :

```
country     sum(day before)  
India       5000  
Southafrica 7000  
Japan       4000
```

I want to display it in a table like this .

```
Country         yesterday   daybefore  
India           4500        5000  
Southafrica     5000        7000    
Japan           empty       4000
```

I have written the DAL based on this tutorial

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/simple-php-class-based-querying/

any help would be great .

```
Query sample : this is run twice in a loop where $date = array('1','2')                                                                                                                                              
query : select c.country_name, sum(tf.tx_amount_usd)
from
table1 tf,
table2 tp,
table3 d,
table4 c
where
tf.condition = tp.condition
and d.day = current_date-$date      
group by 1,2 order by 2
```

Fetching Data :

```
$results = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($res)){
    $result = new DALQueryResult();
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v){
        $result->$k = $v;
    }

    $results[] = $result;
}
return $results;
```

Displaying data :

```
$dal = new DAL(); 
$dates = array('1','2');                                                         
foreach ($dates as $date)  {
    $results = $dal->get_trans_by_date($date);
    echo "<h1>Data</h1>";
    // check if there were any results
    if ($results) {
        // cycle through results
        foreach ($results as $model) {
            /* echo "<pre>";print_r($results);echo "</pre>"; */
            echo "<li>$model->country_name ".number_format($model->sum,2)."</li>";
        }
    }
    else {
        // Display a message concerning lack of data
        echo "<p>No Query Output.</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be easier to give an answer if you provide some of the code you use to retrieve and output your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear of what you are trying to do. All those tags and we do not know wether you're asking for table-builing the data in PHP, or doing it immediately in Postgres.

Assuming you mean in Postgres, here is one way to achieve what you want:

```
@> SELECT name AS country, yesterday_sum, daybefore_sum \
   FROM countries C \
   INNER JOIN iteration2 A ON C.id = A.country \
   LEFT JOIN iteration1 B ON C.id = B.country;

   country   | yesterday_sum | daybefore_sum
-------------+---------------+---------------
 India       |          4500 |          5000
 Southafrica |          5000 |          7000
 Japan       |               |          4000
(3 rows)
```

(I created the tables and inserted the test-data according to your output)

But again, due to the vague question I'm not sure this is what you're asking for so it's just a shot.